# How to get selected loadings in princomp in R

Tags: r, pca

I am trying following code using princomp function and first 4 columns of iris dataset for principal component analysis:

```
prin =princomp(iris[1:4])
loadings(prin)

#Loadings:
#             Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
#Sepal.Length  0.361  0.657 -0.582  0.315
#Sepal.Width          0.730  0.598 -0.320
#Petal.Length  0.857 -0.173        -0.480
#Petal.Width   0.358         0.546  0.754

#               Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4
#SS loadings      1.00   1.00   1.00   1.00
#Proportion Var   0.25   0.25   0.25   0.25
#Cumulative Var   0.25   0.50   0.75   1.00
```

I need the matrix shown in upper part with selected values only (small values have been kept blank there).

However, when I try following code, I get all values (including the values which were blanked out in above output- I want them to be shown as NA or 0):

```
prinl = loadings(prin)
dd = as.data.frame.matrix(prinl)
dd
#                  Comp.1      Comp.2      Comp.3     Comp.4
#Sepal.Length  0.36138659  0.65658877 -0.58202985  0.3154872
#Sepal.Width  -0.08452251  0.73016143  0.59791083 -0.3197231
#Petal.Length  0.85667061 -0.17337266  0.07623608 -0.4798390
#Petal.Width   0.35828920 -0.07548102  0.54583143  0.7536574
```

How can I get a matrix or dataframe with blank values as NA or 0 rather than all values? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just choose some threshold value and replace cells:

```
> threshold <- 0.2
> dd[abs(dd ) < threshold] <- NA
> dd
                Comp.1     Comp.2     Comp.3     Comp.4
Sepal.Length 0.3613866 -0.6565888 -0.5820299  0.3154872
Sepal.Width         NA -0.7301614  0.5979108 -0.3197231
Petal.Length 0.8566706         NA         NA -0.4798390
Petal.Width  0.3582892         NA  0.5458314  0.7536574
```

Comment: What threshold is used by princomp? Is there any formula or a fixed value?

Comment: Looks like a fixed value with default 0.1. You can pass `cutoff` argument to the print function like this: `print(loadings(prin), cutoff=0.4)`.